# Remember div hover state after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation bar that grows in width when it is hovered over.

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gsj27/822/

Now, if for example I have a home button in the area that the hover effect applies to, when it is clicked and the home page is loaded the result is as follows:

The page is loaded with the navigation area in default size (small width), and after an instance it increases in width, as per the hover effect, when the hover effect "kicks in".

**The Question**

How to make the page load with the hover effect keeping its state right before a hyperlink is clicked? So in my example, if the home button is clicked then load home page with the hover effect already active (since home button is on navbar area so hover effect will necessarily be on). But if a hyperlink elsewhere (e.g. gray area in my example) is clicked then load page with hover effect off.

I think this can be achieved using js toggleClass? Something like

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if(/* hover effect was on */) {
                $('nav').toggleClass('hovered');
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save status in url:

```
<a href="?active=true">

if(window.location.href.indexOf('active=true') > 0) {
  $('.nav').addClass('hovered');
}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gsj27/824/
Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gsj27/824/show/

You can also use hash(#) to save status.

Comment: Thanks Francyoung! Your suggestion results in the hover state being always on for the new page since the url is static. So after page reload, hover effect will be on even if cursor is no longer hovering over navbar. How would you fix this?

Comment: Also I just noticed in the demo that when homebutton is clicked then the navbar still goes back to default and expands after reload

Comment: May be u can try save status in localstorage or cookie. But I don't think save status when reload is a good idea. If u change data in current page, may be can render partial page with ajax.